# i18n-node: split up in multiple files for one language

Tags: internationalization, i18n-node

I use the node module `i18n` (with Node & Express) for internationalization. 
Because the json file is becoming so long, I would prefer to use multiple json files for a single language. 
Is this possible within this node module?

I am thinking of for example having a folder for each language with multiple files in that folder. 
Or combining multiple language/json files in a single `en.json` by importing them in `en.json`.

What would be the best way to split up the content in multiple files for a single language, within the boundaries of this node module?

Comment: I have same problem and I think one solution is to generate multiple files and after that parse them and generate new finale one like en.json and nl.json and count all content in this final files.